# NVD3.js - MultiLine Chart Multiple x-axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I know that we can have up to three different Y-axis in a single MultiLine Chart. I need to have a second X-axis. Is this possible?

I'm trying to create a period-over-period time comparison, in which the user can see the same variable plotted for two different time ranges in the same chart.

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible in NVD3, you'd have to use plain D3.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I'm going through https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/nv.d3.js and finding lots of references to a `x2axis` which seems to indicate some degree of support; can this be correct or am I mistaken?

Comment: This is for charts with "viewfinders" like [this one](http://nvd3.org/examples/lineWithFocus.html).

Comment: You are right. It seems the answer is `roll your own`. I'd be happy to mark it correct if you migrate your comment to an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not supported in NVD3, you'll have to implement your own version.